# Can't export environment variable in WSL

Tags: linux, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I feel like I am having a stroke. I am currently running the following export command in WSL:

```
export BROWSER=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe
```

but WSL doesn't seem to recognize that $BROWSER has been overwritten as it keeps running it without the backslashes:

```
echo $BROWSER
```

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe
```

Which causes the following error when running the command:

```
$BROWSER
```

```
bash: /mnt/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Is this a bug in WSL? Or have I made a mistake setting environment variables?

EDIT:

I also tried it using quotes instead of slashes:

```
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
```

Comment: Use a quote for that path.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for the comment. Gave it a shot using `export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'` but there was no difference.

Comment: I actually could simply run echo $BROWSER using WSL2 because it was correcting the path:

`$> export BROWSER=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe`
`$> echo $BROWSER`
`/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the painful world of POSIX compatible shell behavior.

The backslashes in the assignment "escape" the space characters. Which means they are not treated as whitespace that would normally terminate the string. The backslashes are removed because they served their purpose. This has nothing to do with environment variables. It's how backslashes work in a POSIX shell. Try `echo a\ b\"c`.

Then, when you used `$BROWSER`, the shell replaced that variable reference with the value of the variable. It then split the result on the value of the `$IFS` variable. Since `$IFS` normally contains space, tab, and newline the browser path was split on the embedded spaces into three distinct strings. You can see this happen by running `printf "%s\n" $BROWSER`.

The solution is to quote the variable expansion to inhibit the `$IFS` splitting. In other words, use `"$BROWSER"`. In fact, you should almost always place variable expansion inside double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer here. +1 I'm wondering if you have a recommendation for a more elegant approach than what I'm doing here to fix .env in WSL? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836810/470749

Comment: Sorry, @Ryan, I don't know anything about Heroku. What you're doing in the comment you linked to is simply bypassing the .env file and setting the environment variables before starting the server. That is no different than doing `export SOME_VAR=some_val` before running any other command. Note that your problem has nothing to do with WSL per se. WSL is simply a Ubuntu Linux user space. If you actually setup a Ubuntu based server outside of Windows 10 you would run into the same problem because the problem lies with your config of Heroku and related software, not WSL.

Comment: ❤️ I appreciate your response and apologize for being unclear: I don’t have anything to do with Heroku; that was the question-asker (not me). I guess I was being lazy and not writing a full new question. Basically my situation is just that .env has always worked for me except when developing within WSL. I wrote (as an answer to that other person) just what my hacky workaround is. I’m curious to solve it more permanently. Thanks for the time you spent responding, and my apologies.